# Impala double values not getting loaded correctly

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, impala

I have created a simple table in impala like below

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_db.employee
   (name STRING, salary double );
```

And my insert statement is like below

```
insert into employee (name, salary)
    VALUES ("Prasad", 158.17)
```

But the problem is

My values in impala is getting loaded as

```
name,salary
prasad,158.1666666666
```

I don't understand why this is happening. I have tried in other db's like hive but the value is getting loaded as 158.17 but in impala it is 158.1666666666

Can you please help me why this is happening ...

And how to load actual values...

Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of floating point versus fixed point arithmetic.  If you want the decimal portion to be exact, use `decimal`/`numeric` for the column:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_db.employee 
    name STRING,
    salary DECIMAL(10, 2)
);
```